# Can a Table Column be Rich Text / WYSIWYG?

Tags: richtext, table-field

The only types in the list are `Single-line text`, `Multi-line text`, `Number` or `Checkbox`.

Answer (score 3):

I think that's actually a table field type you are referring to, not a Matrix Field Type.

Matrix field types can indeed have Rich Text. There are a lot of instances where a Matrix field can be used in place of a table field.

Comment: Okay, so ignore the word Matrix in my original question. Can a table column be rich text?

Comment: Nope, that's why I brought it up. @Brandon Kelly has mentioned it a couple of times that if you need Rich Text stuff in tabular data, it's probably best to go with a Matrix. People have tried debating the issue, but that's currently where it stands.